# Remove using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have added a image using the statement

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children('#control).before("<img src='../cx.gif' />");
```

On click of another button I want to remove the appended image.

How to do it.
Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I know of the prev() function, so assuming you don't prepend that image more than once, maybe try:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().children('#control').prev().remove()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways of doing so:

- Give the image an ID
- Give the image a class
- Keep a reference to the image

Then just use whichever selector is needed for the method you choose and call:

```
$('#uniqueID').remove();
$('.className').remove();
imageReference.remove(); // if you did var imageReference = $(this).parent().siblings().children('#control).before("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it an ID or suitable identifier such as a class, then remove it by selector:

```
$('#img').remove();//by id
$('.myImg').remove();//by class
```